# Two urns problem

Tags: probability-theory

There are two urns on a table. Urn number 1 contains four white marbles and two red marbles each. Urn number 2 contains one white marbles and five red marble. Without looking, a marble is selected at random from urn number 1 and placed in urn number 2. Finally, a marble is selected at random from urn number 2. What is the probability that the marble selected from urn number 2 is red? Here is what I did: 6/7*5/7=0.6122

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so there's a 1/3$ chance the marble transferred from urn 1 is red.

If it's red, then urn 2 has one white marble and six red marbles, so there is a $6/7$ probability of drawing red.

If the marble transferred is white (which happens $2/3$ of the time) then urn 2 has two white marbles and five red marbles, so the probability of drawing red is $5/7.$

Thus the total probability of drawing red is $$ \frac{1}{3}\frac{6}{7} + \frac{2}{3}\frac{5}{7} = \frac{16}{21}$$

Comment: That seems right. I appreciate your help. I posted another question on lie detector test and I will provide my answers shortly. If you can please look at it that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer $6/7 \times 5/7$ is close, but not correct. You forgot to consider that the cases themselves have a different probability of occuring.

---

**Case 1**: Marble selected from Urn 1 and placed in Urn 2 was red:

This case itself has a probability $1/3$ of happening, and once it happens, Urn 2 then has $1$ white marble and $5+1=6$ red marbles. We pick red in this Urn 2 with probability $6/7$ now. So, our final probability for this case is $\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{6}{7} = \frac{6}{21}$.

**Case 2**: Marble selected from Urn 1 and placed in Urn 2 was white:

This case itself has a probability $2/3$ of happening, and once it happens, Urn 2 then has $1+1=2$ white marbles and $5$ red marbles. We pick red in this Urn 2 with probability $5/7$ now. So, our final probability for this case is $\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{5}{7} = \frac{10}{21}$.

The final answer is $\frac{6}{21} + \frac{10}{21} = \boxed{\frac{16}{21}}$.

$\square$